# How to embed instagram images using their ID? (React)

Tags: reactjs

Quick question, I am doing some research on how to embed images from instagram profile without using the short code e.g. if this is the URL of the image: https://www.instagram.com/p/CdpH67-sZie/, CdpH67-sZie is the shortcode.

Now I have found a solution to embed them with short code using this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-instagram-embed

Does anyone know if there is a way to embed images using their ID in React? While also doing my own research I figured it would be good to ask here as well just in case someone has already done this, I have found the way to get the ID of the image, but don't know how to implement that without using the link with short code.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to fetch the images from the Instagram Graph API.

react-instagram-embed does this by using the aforementioned API but the repository seems abandoned as the documentation redirects to deprecated methods.
Which is why you could be better of forking the repo or just doing your own calls to the official API with for example axios.